# Esconder elemento com angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Olá.
Tenho uma rotina que verifica os elementos de um form-group e adiciona a classe **has-error** no form-validate. Segue abaixo

```
var allElements = element.find("input");

for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
var field = angular.element(allElements[i]);
   if(field.parent().parent().hasClass('has-error')){                                              field.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
                                    }
                            }
```

**E O FORM-GROUP ESTÁ ASSIM**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group plain-addon">                           
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></span></div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.nickname" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" name="nickname" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"><span class="help-block">Campo obrigatório</span></span>
</div>
```

Preciso agora esconder o Campo obrigatório e só mostrar quando **has-error**. Estou começando agora em angularjs

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar **ng-hide** para esconder e o **ng-show** para exibir a tag html ou ng-if para que o componente só exista se for verdadeiro

Maiores informações link 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Answer (score 0):

Acho que com **css** você consegue resolver, você pode adicionar uma classe junto com o `help-block` ou usá-lo (dependendo da sua utilidade na aplicação, isso pode não ser interessante) tente algo do tipo;

```
.help-block {
  display: none;
}
.has-error .help-block {
  display: block;
}
```

Caso opte por criar uma classe específica para isso é só substituir o help-block por ela.